# How can I implement a 'random mine placer' in PHP

Tags: php

For a project im making a minesweeper game. So im looking to implement a random mine placer in my PHP code. I made a dynamic table using the following code:

```
<?php

$rows = 6; //  amount of rows
$cols = 6;  //  amount of columns

echo "<table border='1'>";

for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){

    echo "<tr>";
    for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Now the thing is that I need to be able to let the mines spawn in a random cell every time I would restart the game. Anyone that could help me out?

Comment: This might be a bit of a broad question. I think the best bet would probably create an array of possible bomb locations, shuffle it a few times, then splice it to the number of bombs you want. The harder part would be counting the number of bombs around an empty space.

Comment: Take the number of fields. Order them by random and select the first n and place bombs there

Comment: what the exact problem you are facing right now?

Comment: The current problem im running into is that I need to be able to change the amount of generated bombs by changing a number, for instance from 1 mine to 4 mines. It also shouldn't be able to place 2 bombs at the same place. So it will have to check if there's already a bomb placed in that location and if so it should go on and find an empty cell. And since im really just starting out learning to write code I need all the help I can get :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To spawn one new bomb, generate a random row and column and check for it:

```
$rows = 6;  //  amount of rows
$cols = 6;  //  amount of columns
$rand_row = rand(1, 6);  // random row
$rand_col = rand(1, 6);  // random column

echo "<table border='1'>";

for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){    
    echo "<tr>";

    for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
        echo "<td>";

        if($tr == $rand_row && $td == $rand_col) { // check for row and column
            echo "***BOMB***";
        }        
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: By using this the code did what I intended to let it do. The only problem is that it seems to create an enormous amount of extra td's, 93700 to be exact. So I guess I would have to let it know that it cant create extra cells?

Comment: Oh well it created another 93700 td's. Since im new to coding thats very strange to me

Comment: Doh, had a typo make sure `if` comparisons are `==` or `===`.

Comment: That seemed to fix it, thanks alot. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the rand() function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

You could use that to generate random row + column numbers for where the bombs should be placed, or to randomly decide if a cell should or shouldn't have a bomb in it, depending on how you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing in php using Symfony console. You can have a look my code
It's simple just few classes
https://github.com/digitaldreams/minesweeper